# How to use NPM package in Vue if it requires Nodejs filesystem (fs)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Every time I attempt to use an NPM package in Vue that requires `fs` it doesn't work and it errors out. Normally along the lines of `fs could not be resolved` or `fs.readFileSync is not a function`.

I have seen some other pages that say `fs` doesn't work in browsers because of permission etc...

Just to add, I am not explicitly trying to use the fs module. I am just trying to use the npm package which happens to use fs.

What should I do to make it work? Ive tested these packages on the npm runkit, and everything is fine. And that runs in a browser, so I'm a little confused there also.

Comment: Can you indicate which `npm` package causes the issue?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszhuyin this is the one I’m having problems with right now. In the main.js file there is a line that requires fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that Vue will be rendered client side.
fs is just for node applications, because it is server side (you should not be able to read data from a client file system).
You you have two options:

1. Not using the module
2. Or, if you do not need the fs part and the module is under a open source
   license (which 
   the module you mentioned in comments is): copying the module and removing the 
   fs part